# xpath multiple conditions with different tags

Tags: xml, validation, xpath, conditional-statements, cda

I have a problem with validate xml document, I need to arrive to target with tags `<templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.33.4.4"/>` and it `<entryRelationship>`, both conditions must achieve, because if these two conditions achieve ,I will be able to check if entryRelationship has `<templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.33.4.2"/>`. I have done this:

```
<rule context="//cda:entry/cda:organizer/cda:component/cda:observation[(./templateId/*[@root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.33.4.4']) and (./entryRelationship/*[@typeCode='REFR'])]">
   <!--<rule context='*[cda:templateId/@root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.33.4.4"]'>-->
   <assert test="self::cda:entryRelationship[@typeCode='REFR']">
      FAIL: CONF-QR-176: The entryRelationship, if present, SHALL contain exactly one [1..1] @typeCode="REFR" (CodeSystem: HL7ActRelationshipType 2.16.840.1.113883.5.1002).  Line: 
      <value-of select="@_line"/>
   </assert>
   <assert test="count(cda:entryRelationship/cda:observation/cda:templateId[@root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.33.4.2'])=1">
      FAIL: CONF-QR-177: The entryRelationship, if present,SHALL contain exactly one [1..1] Question Help Text Pattern Observation template (templateId 2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.32.4.19).  Line: 
      <value-of select="@_line"/>
   </assert>
</rule>
```

but not work,I need help, thanks very much.

This is xml:

```
<component>
   <sequenceNumber value="4"/>
   <observation classCode="OBS" moodCode="EVN">
      <!--templateID for the Numeric Response Pattern-->
      <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.33.4.4"/>
      <languageCode></languageCode>
      <entryRelationship typeCode="REFR">
         <!--templateID for Response Media Pattern template-->
         <!--<templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.33.4.2"/>-->
      </entryRelationship>
      <id extension="ob4" root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.1817.1.6"/>
      <code code="q4" codeSystem="Continua-Q-OID">
         <originalText>How many hours did you sleep last night?</originalText>
      </code>
      <statusCode code="COMPLETED"/>
      <value xsi:type="INT" value="7"/>
      <referenceRange typeCode="REFV">
         <!--templateID for the Response Reference Range Pattern-->
         <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.33.4.3"/>
         <observationRange>
            <text></text>
            <value xsi:type="IVL_INT">
               <low value="0"/>
               <high value="24"/>
            </value>
         </observationRange>
      </referenceRange>
   </observation>
</component>
```

Comment: check my updated answer. Also, update your question instead of posting updates as answer (like your answer that has been deleted)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, based on your xpath for rule context attribute, you can try this way (formatted for readability) :

```
//cda:entry
/cda:organizer
/cda:component
/cda:observation[
    templateId/@root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.33.4.4' 
        and 
    entryRelationship/@typeCode='REFR'
]
```

Then regarding xpath for "assert test", since the context node is `<observation>`, `self::cda:entryRelationship` doesn't make much sense to me. Try this instead -or maybe without `/` at the beginning- :

```
<assert test="/cda:entryRelationship[@typeCode='REFR']">
```

`<entryRelationship>` is child of context node, not the context node it self, so the above expression makes more sense to try.